# cast image from stream

Tags: c#, winforms

am using the cell click event for data grid view, and am finding problems trying to cast image from stream

```
  private void abaanaCCDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Ptxtspn_code.Text = this.abaanaCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name].Value.ToString();
        //this.PtxtFname.Text

        this.abaanaCCTableAdapter.Fill(this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC);
       byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[0]["CCImage"];
        //byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[this.dataGridViewImageColumn1.Name];
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
        //Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        this.PpicBox.Image = (Image.FromStream(stream))abaanaCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[this.dataGridViewImageColumn1.Name].Value;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? I can see that your last line won't even compile.

Comment: i want to display byte image into picturebox, such that when a row is selected, image column is selected as well

Comment: And what are you trying to do? Why doesn't `this.PpicBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)` work?

Comment: To assign your `byte[]` as `Image` of your `PpicBox` its enough to `var stream=new MemoryStream(mydata ); PpicBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);`

Comment: What do other codes supposed to do?

Comment: the first line displays selected value of column `this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name` in  `this.Ptxtspn_code.Text` Text Box the 2nd, 3rd and 4th line, i am trying to convert byte image back to image. in the 5th line i am trying to cast an image(from stream) to display in the picture box. such that when a row is selected from `dataGridView` image appears in `this.PpicBox.Image`

Answer (score 2):

That line makes no sense:

```
(Image.FromStream(stream)abaanaCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[this.dataGridViewImageColumn1.Name].Value
```

I cannot see why you put `Image.FromStream(stream)` and `abaanaCCDataGridView...` together?

Basically what you do is not incorrect. Get a `MemoryStream` from your `byte[]` and call `Image.FromStream()`.

So I think these lines will work for you ...

```
byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[0]["CCImage"];
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
this.PpicBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

... if the content of the `byte[]` is valid.

Comment: finding a problem selecting a whole row of the `dataGridView` one of them being image column